# How do I gulp.src an entire folder and its subfolders, and then gulp.dest based on files' location?

Tags: gulp

**EDIT:** is there a way to clean up this code?

task.coffee

```
# Watch pages
gulp.task 'jade', ->
  # Watch index
  gulp.src('src/jade/index.jade')
  .pipe(jade(pretty: true))
  .pipe gulp.dest('dist')
  # Watch views
  gulp.src('src/jade/views/*.jade')
  .pipe(jade(pretty: true))
  .pipe gulp.dest('dist/views')
  # Watch views/products
  gulp.src('src/jade/views/products/*.jade')
  .pipe(jade(pretty: true))
  .pipe gulp.dest('dist/views/products')

gulp.watch 'src/jade/*.jade', ['html']
gulp.task 'html', (callback) ->
  runSequence 'jade', callback
  return
```

---

Let's say I'm running my gulp task to process my .jade files and I'm working on an angular app (views/**/*.html), how do I keep clean my task in order to change my task to do this?

```
// gulp.src('src/jade/**/*.jade')
// gulp.dest('dist/path/*.html') so for example 'src/jade/index.jade'
// will be output into 'dist/index.html' and
// 'src/jade/views/products/product.jade' will be
// output into 'dist/views/products/product.html'
```

task.coffee

```
# Watch pages
gulp.task 'jade', ->
  gulp.src('src/jade/*.jade')
  .pipe(jade(pretty: true))
  .pipe gulp.dest('dist')
gulp.watch 'src/jade/*.jade', ['html']
gulp.task 'html', (callback) ->
  runSequence 'jade', callback
  return
```

task.js

```
gulp.task('jade', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/jade/*.jade').pipe(jade({
    pretty: true
  })).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.watch('src/jade/*.jade', ['html']);

gulp.task('html', function(callback) {
  runSequence('jade', callback);
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to your question is already in your own post:

```
// gulp.src('src/jade/**/*.jade')
```

Using this in you `jade` task and `watch` should accomplish exactly what you want:

```
gulp.task('jade', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/jade/**/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.watch('src/jade/**/*.jade', ['html']);
```

This will produce files in the `dist` folder like so:

```
src/jade/index.jade -> dist/index.html
src/jade/views/example.jade -> dist/views/example.html
src/jade/views/products/product.jade -> dist/views/products/product.html
...
```

Comment: Will each file output in the corresponding path, automatically? Does gulp.dest('dist') just change 'src/path/of/the/*.file' into 'dist/path/of/the/*.file'?

Comment: Yes, see my edited answer. Everything before to the `**` gets stripped away (i.e. `src/jade/`) but the folder structure after the `**` is preserved.